# Opening chrome extension in new tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is this still valid?

```
"app": {
    "launch": {
      "local_path": "window.html",
      "container": "tab"

    }
  },
```

I'm using Chrome v46 and it works but I'd like to be sure it is not a bug.
I cannot see anything like this in the [manifest file reference](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manifest snippet (containing `app.launch.local_path`) describes a [legacy packaged app](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/apps). These are deprecated and not officially supported any more.

If you want to have an icon in the app launcher, then you need to [create a Chrome app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app) (if you want to host the content in the package) or a [hosted app](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/hosted_apps) (if you want to host the content online).

If you don't want to create an app, but an [extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions), then you could use a [browser action button](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) to add a button to the toolbar, and then open a page in a new tab using [`chrome.tabs.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create). Or, if your actual goal is replacing the new tab page, use [`chrome_url_overrides` to override `newtab`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override).